# Auto sync two folders in my home folder

Tags: linux, debian, rsync

I'm running Debian and I want to automatically sync changes made in one folder to another folder. Both folders are sub folders of my home folder. This just needs to be one way sync.

I have looked at rsync and I can get what I want by typing the command:

```
rsync -rv --delete one/ two
```

I'd just like to have this automatically run so that changes made to one are reflected in the other. I know that rsync can be run as a daemon but I'm not sure of the security configuration I'd need for this and ideally I don't want to have to make these folders visible to all users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably use [inosync](https://github.com/hollow/inosync#readme) or [incron](http://linux.die.net/man/8/incrond) to trigger off rsync or any other command when the source folder is altered.

I'm familiar with incron so I'll deal with that. Install incron via your package manager. Edit `/etc/incron.allow` and add the users you want to allow to use incron.

`incrontab -e` then add the line `IN_MODIFY /source/ command` replacing command with the rsync command you want to run. See the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/5/incrontab) for incrontab for more ideas on triggers

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to the [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) project, it's designed for that.